# Getting only on row from the array, Can't Store More than one Row Its Overwriting

Tags: android

Using addFavorite Method Getting only on row from the array, Can't Store More than one Row Its Overwriting using getfavourites method if Anny one know this Problem Please Tell me A Solution
Thanks In Advance

```
 public class SharedPreference {

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "PRODUCT_APP";
    public static final String FAVORITES = "Product_Favorite";

    public SharedPreference() {
        super();
    }

    // This four methods are used for maintaining favorites.
    public void saveFavorites(Context context, List<Product> favorites) {
        SharedPreferences settings;
        Editor editor;

        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = settings.edit();

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonFavorites = gson.toJson(favorites);

        editor.putString(FAVORITES, jsonFavorites);

        editor.commit();
    }

    public void addFavorite(Context context, Product product) {
        List<Product> favorites = getFavorites(context);
        if (favorites == null)
            favorites = new ArrayList<Product>();
        favorites.add(product);
        saveFavorites(context, favorites);
    }

    public void removeFavorite(Context context, Product product) {
        ArrayList<Product> favorites = getFavorites(context);
        if (favorites != null) {
            favorites.remove(product);
            saveFavorites(context, favorites);
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Product> getFavorites(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences settings;
        List<Product> favorites;

        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        if (settings.contains(FAVORITES)) {
            String jsonFavorites = settings.getString(FAVORITES, null);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Product[] favoriteItems = gson.fromJson(jsonFavorites,
                    Product[].class);

            favorites = Arrays.asList(favoriteItems);
            favorites = new ArrayList<Product>(favorites);
        } else
            return null;

        return (ArrayList<Product>) favorites;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time in add method you are using new keyword which mean you are overwriting your previous list with new list. 
You need to first getList from Stored Share Prefrences and 
then add new Item to that List.

```
public void addFavorite(Context context, Product product) {
    List<Product> favorites = new ArrayList<Product>();


    // this line cause you problem.
    //   favorites = new ArrayList<Product>();
    // this line cause you problem.

    // add code from below line

    favorites=getFavorites(context);
    if(favorites!=null)
    {
        favorites.add(product);
    }

    saveFavorites(context, favorites);
}
```

Comment: Thanks For the effort to Helping me, Problem was on another place  , Thanks for the clue buddy..............